# Obtain an xpath element containing another element with an specific class

Tags: xpath

Hello I have this HTML:

```
<div class="_3Vhpd"><span>Your commerce Data</span>
<a class="n3G0C" href='http://www.webadress.......'><span>Some Text</span</a>
</div>
```

I tried to obtain the  tag as follow:

```
parser.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"_3Vhpd")]//following-sibling::*[a[@class="n3G0C"]]/@href ')
```

but I received none '[]'. Maybe because  is not just after div but after a span...

Comment: It looks like you may be saying that you received and empty array.  Please state your question more clearly and you are more likely to get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you sample html doesn't have a `class="n3G0C"`, but assuming you fix it, this xpath expression should work:

```
//div[contains(@class,"_3Vhpd")]//following-sibling::a/@href
```

Output:

> http://www.webadress.......

Comment: I have modified the original post

Comment: Still not working, return []... can I use following-sibling even the element <a> is not the next one after the div?

Comment: Using child:: instead of following-sibling is working

Comment: @bartoro - If it works like that on your actual html, then just use `//div[contains(@class,"_3Vhpd")]//a/@href`.